# React setState and use the value to update another state

Tags: reactjs, use-state, setstate

I have a simple roll the dice code and I want to update the score based on the dice roll.

This is the states of the dices and the scores:

```
 const [Dice1, setDice1] = useState(0);
 const [Dice2, setDice2] = useState(0);

 const [Score1, setScore1] = useState(0);
 const [Score2, setScore2] = useState(0);

 function randomNum() {
      setDice2(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
      setDice1(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
      Dice1 > Dice2 && Dice1 !== Dice2 ? setScore1(Score1 + 1) : Dice2 > Dice1 && Dice1 !== Dice2 ? setScore2(Score2 + 1) : setScore2(Score2 + 0);
 }
```

The function randomNum is triggered on click.

```
 return (
      <div className="App">
           <header className="App-header">
                <p>Player 1 rolls {Dice1}</p>
                <p>Player 2 rolls {Dice2}</p>
                <button onClick={randomNum}>Roll the dice</button>
                {Dice1 > Dice2 ? <p>Player 1 win</p> : Dice1 === Dice2 ? <p>Draw</p> : <p>Player 2 win</p>}
                <p>Player 1 score is {Score1} points</p>
                <p>Player 2 score is {Score2} points</p>
                <button onClick={resetScore}>Reset score</button>
           </header>
      </div>
 );
```

Everything works well, except that the score if updated with 1 round lag.
Everytime I roll, it is added the point from the last round.
What am I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

One Score state would look like

```
  const [score, setScore] = useState({
    score1: 0,
    score2: 0
  });
```

You can update like

```
  setScore(prev=>{...prev, score1: prev.score1 + 1})
setScore(prev=>{...prev, score2: prev.score2 + 1})
```

---

Try this

1. Use one state for dice instead

```
const [dice, setDice] = useState({
    dice1: 0,
    dice2: 0,
  })
```

2. Update the state

```
function randomNum() {
    const dice1Val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    const dice2val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    setDice({
      dice1: dice1Val,
      dice2val: dice2Val
    })
```

3. And since setting score is an effect of setting dice, update the score in a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
      dice.dice1 > dice.dice2 && dice.dice1 !== dice.dice2 ? setScore1(prev => prev + 1); : dice.dice2 > dice.dice1 && dice.dice1 !== dice.dice2 ? setScore2(prev => prev + 1) : setScore2(prev => prev + 1)
    },[dice])
 }
```

You can also put the scores under one state instead.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I will read about useEffect and that prev => prev function because at this moment, I don't understand how it works.

I made one state for scores aswell but I'm not sure how to rewrite the useEffect now, i tried this but it seems it dosen't work

setScore({ score1: (prev) => prev + 1 })

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way I can think of is to implement the resetScore function that will set the both states to 0.

`function resetScore() { setScore1(0); setScore2(0); }`

or call this function at the start of the randomNum.

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the previous state values correctly. It is not recommended to use previous state values directly while updating state variables.

So in your code instead of :

```
setScore1(Score1 + 1)
```

you should do like this :

```
setScore1(prevScore => prevScore + 1);
```

and similarly for other state variables.